# How would I go about detecting links in TTTAttributedLabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a table view and in some of the cells there are links, I want to be allow the user to click on these links and view them in a webView (which I have already made). I don't want to use the row selection event because there may be more than one link in the cell. I came across TTTAttributedLabel and think it will be ideal. I don't need to add any style to the text in the cell, I only need to detect the links and capture the click event to open up my webview.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can assign a `TTTAttributedLabelDelegate` to a `TTTAttributedLabel` that will get call backs for when a user selects different link types, but no opportunity for you to capture them and open your own web view (which I think is what you're trying to accomplish).

Instead, you might wanna check out [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel). It's similar in functionality, but when a user clicks on one of the links in the label, it calls `-(BOOL)attributedLabel:(OHAttributedLabel*)attributedLabel shouldFollowLink:(NSTextCheckingResult*)linkInfo` on it's `OHAttributedLabelDelegate`, which gives you the opportunity to handle the link tap yourself if you return `NO`.

Comment: Yep I figured it our but have not had time to enter my solution, I will do soon.